# How can I test a wsdl with phpunit?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, phpunit

I am new to PHP and need to write automated tests to test a WSDL with phpunit. I did not find much practical material with baby steps to help me. Someone to give me some help getting started?

Comment: Do you actually want to test the web service the WSDL file describes or the file itself? To test the web service you can look into the [SoapClient class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) from PHP itself, there are some small examples on how to use it.

Comment: I want to do functional tests on webservice. I think that the SoapClient doesn't actually perform that kind of test. I want to do an external call to the wsdl...